# Docker compose kong with postgres (Kong keep restarting)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, migration, kong

im new to docker
Wanted to know what cause of kong image keeps restarting when i check the log its keep looping the log of `Database already bootstrapped` then restart.

Note: kong was already working without database if `- KONG_DATABASE=off` but now when i try add database of postgres this happen: kindly check the log.

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
 kong-net:
  driver: bridge

    
services: 

  kong-database:
    image: postgres:14
    restart: always
    networks:
      - kong-net
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=kong
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=kong
      - POSTGRES_DB=kong
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"


  
  kong:
    image: kong:latest
    command: "kong migrations bootstrap"
    container_name: kong
    restart: always
    networks:
      - kong-net
    volumes:
      - ./kong.yml:/usr/local/kong/declarative/kong.yml
    environment:
      - KONG_DATABASE=postgres
      - KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database
      - KONG_PG_PORT=5432
      - KONG_PG_USER=kong
      - KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kong
      - KONG_PG_DATABASE=kong
      - KONG_DECLARATIVE_CONFIG=/usr/local/kong/declarative/kong.yml
      - KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl
    depends_on:

      - kong-database
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "8443:8443"
      - "127.0.0.1:8001:8001"
      - "127.0.0.1:8444:8444"
```

log of kong

```
Bootstrapping database...

migrating core on database 'kong'...

core migrated up to: 000_base (executed)

core migrated up to: 003_100_to_110 (executed)

core migrated up to: 004_110_to_120 (executed)

core migrated up to: 005_120_to_130 (executed)

core migrated up to: 006_130_to_140 (executed)

core migrated up to: 007_140_to_150 (executed)

core migrated up to: 008_150_to_200 (executed)

core migrated up to: 009_200_to_210 (executed)

core migrated up to: 010_210_to_211 (executed)

core migrated up to: 011_212_to_213 (executed)

core migrated up to: 012_213_to_220 (executed)

core migrated up to: 013_220_to_230 (executed)

core migrated up to: 014_230_to_270 (executed)

core migrated up to: 015_270_to_280 (executed)

core migrated up to: 016_280_to_300 (executed)

core migrated up to: 017_300_to_310 (executed)

core migrated up to: 018_310_to_320 (executed)

migrating acl on database 'kong'...

acl migrated up to: 000_base_acl (executed)

acl migrated up to: 002_130_to_140 (executed)

acl migrated up to: 003_200_to_210 (executed)

acl migrated up to: 004_212_to_213 (executed)

migrating acme on database 'kong'...

acme migrated up to: 000_base_acme (executed)

acme migrated up to: 001_280_to_300 (executed)

migrating basic-auth on database 'kong'...

basic-auth migrated up to: 000_base_basic_auth (executed)

basic-auth migrated up to: 002_130_to_140 (executed)

basic-auth migrated up to: 003_200_to_210 (executed)

migrating bot-detection on database 'kong'...

bot-detection migrated up to: 001_200_to_210 (executed)

migrating hmac-auth on database 'kong'...

hmac-auth migrated up to: 000_base_hmac_auth (executed)

hmac-auth migrated up to: 002_130_to_140 (executed)

hmac-auth migrated up to: 003_200_to_210 (executed)

migrating http-log on database 'kong'...

http-log migrated up to: 001_280_to_300 (executed)

migrating ip-restriction on database 'kong'...

ip-restriction migrated up to: 001_200_to_210 (executed)

migrating jwt on database 'kong'...

jwt migrated up to: 000_base_jwt (executed)

jwt migrated up to: 002_130_to_140 (executed)

jwt migrated up to: 003_200_to_210 (executed)

migrating key-auth on database 'kong'...

key-auth migrated up to: 000_base_key_auth (executed)

key-auth migrated up to: 002_130_to_140 (executed)

key-auth migrated up to: 003_200_to_210 (executed)

migrating oauth2 on database 'kong'...

oauth2 migrated up to: 000_base_oauth2 (executed)

oauth2 migrated up to: 003_130_to_140 (executed)

oauth2 migrated up to: 004_200_to_210 (executed)

oauth2 migrated up to: 005_210_to_211 (executed)

migrating post-function on database 'kong'...

post-function migrated up to: 001_280_to_300 (executed)

migrating pre-function on database 'kong'...

pre-function migrated up to: 001_280_to_300 (executed)

migrating rate-limiting on database 'kong'...

rate-limiting migrated up to: 000_base_rate_limiting (executed)

rate-limiting migrated up to: 003_10_to_112 (executed)

rate-limiting migrated up to: 004_200_to_210 (executed)

migrating response-ratelimiting on database 'kong'...

response-ratelimiting migrated up to: 000_base_response_rate_limiting (executed)

migrating session on database 'kong'...

session migrated up to: 000_base_session (executed)

session migrated up to: 001_add_ttl_index (executed)

50 migrations processed

50 executed

Database is up-to-date

Database already bootstrapped

Database already bootstrapped

Database already bootstrapped

Database already bootstrapped

Database already bootstrapped

Database already bootstrapped

Database already bootstrapped

Database already bootstrapped

Database already bootstrapped
```

Answer (score 1):

The manual in the docker-hub says you have to run the database migrations with an ephemeral Kong container.
See "How to use this image with a Database" point 2 of the docs:
https://hub.docker.com/_/kong

You could also check out the docker-compose.yaml for Kong/docker-kong on Github:
https://github.com/Kong/docker-kong/blob/master/compose/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

You'll need a migration container like so:

```yaml
  kong-migration:
    image: kong:latest
    command: "kong migrations bootstrap"
    container_name: kong-migration
    restart: on-failure # Makes sure the container is not restarted unless there was a failure
    networks:
      - kong-net
    environment:
      - KONG_DATABASE=postgres
      - KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database
      - KONG_PG_PORT=5432
      - KONG_PG_USER=kong
      - KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kong
      - KONG_PG_DATABASE=kong
    depends_on:
      - kong-database
```

Also update your Kong container to depend on the DB and migration

```yaml
  kong:
    image: kong:latest
    container_name: kong
    restart: always
    networks:
      - kong-net
    environment:
      - KONG_DATABASE=postgres
      - KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database
      - KONG_PG_PORT=5432
      - KONG_PG_USER=kong
      - KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kong
      - KONG_PG_DATABASE=kong
      - KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl
    depends_on:
      - kong-migration
      - kong-database
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "8443:8443"
      - "127.0.0.1:8001:8001"
      - "127.0.0.1:8444:8444"
```